# Covariant safe cast in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, casting, covariance

I'm trying to write a safe cast for a class with a covariant type parameter like:

```
case class Foo[+A](a: A) {
  def safeCast[B <: A](): Option[B] = ???
}
```

It's being populated by a dynamic external data source, but I at least want to ensure statically that `B` is a subclass of `A`, then return a `None` if the typecast fails. I keep getting errors about `A` being in a covariant position. I can get it to typecheck by leaving off the `<: A`, but how can I specify this static guarantee about `B`?

I know it is preventing situations like assigning a `Foo[Dog]` to a `Foo[Animal]` val, then trying to do something like `safeCast[Mammal]` where `Mammal` isn't a subtype of `Dog`. That's actually okay in my case. Even allowing casting to a supertype of `Animal` would be okay. I mostly want to statically prevent someone trying a `safeCast[Plant]`.

Note, I can get it to typecheck with a function external to the class like the following, but I'm wanting a method on the class.

```
def safeCast[A, B <: A](foo: Foo[A]): Option[B] = ???
```

As a bonus, if you know of a way to implement this using cats or something without `isInstanceOf`, that would be very useful.

Comment: Trouble is, `Foo[A] <: Foo[Any]`, and `B <: Any` too, so your method will always be applicable, no matter what `A` and `B` are.

Answer (score 5):

What about a **typeclass** approach.

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

@annotation.implicitNotFound("${B} is not a subtype of ${A}")
sealed trait Caster[A, B] {
  def safeCast(a: A): Option[B]
}

object Caster {
  implicit def subtypeCaster[A, B](implicit ev: B <:< A, ct: ClassTag[B]): Caster[A, B] =
    new Caster[A, B] {
      override final def safeCast(a: A): Option[B] =
        ct.unapply(a)
    }
}
```

Which can be used like this:

```
sealed trait Animal
final case class Dog(name: String) extends Animal
final case class Cat(name: String) extends Animal

final case class Foo[+A](a: A)

implicit class FooOps[A] (private val foo: Foo[A]) extends AnyVal {
  @inline
  final def safeCastAs[B](implicit caster: Caster[A, B]): Option[Foo[B]] =
    caster.safeCast(foo.a).map(b => Foo(b))
}

val animal: Foo[Animal] = Foo(Dog("luis"))

animal.safeCastAs[Dog] 
// res: Option[Foo[Dog]] = Some(Foo(Dog("luis")))

animal.safeCastAs[Cat] 
// res: Option[Foo[Cat]] = None

animal.safeCastAs[String] 
// compile error: String is not a subtype of Animal
```

---

Two important notes:

- The trick here is to define the method outside the class as an extension method.
  *(at that point one may even consider dropping the typeclass altogether and just use the implicit evidence and the classtag themselves on the extension method)*.
- Due to the use of classtag, you should take care that both **A** & **B** are just plain types. If they are higher kinded types like **List**, you may end up with runtime errors.

Comment: This might solve the problem OP has, but it doesn't actually interact with `Foo`, and therefore bypasses the covariance problem. By the time you call `animal.safeCastAs[Dog]`, `animal` is typed `Animal`, so you're just asking whether `Dog <: Animal`. If you were in a scope where instead of `Animal` you had a covariant `+A`, I don't think it would work.

Comment: @gandaliter You are right, I forgot about `Foo`.  I have edited the answer.

Comment: Makes sense. You still have the problem that `animal` could be typed as `Foo[Any]` and then someone could call `animal.safeCastAs[Plant]`, but I'm not sure there's any way to get around that.

Comment: @gandaliter At that point there is nothing to do, if you have an **Any** anything is a valid subtype of that.

Comment: Yeah exactly. I think this is probably the best that can be done to answer the question as it's written.